# Evil Hangman Project Java not working- My program is not allowing me to input guesses for letters

Tags: java

After I input the number of letters I want the word for the computer to use for me to guess it, for example, I type 4, the program is terminated. I have spent some time debugging it but I cannot figure out the problem. I want the program to ask me to input a letter after inputting the length of the word, but it does not. instead, the program terminates after I input the number and I cannot type anything How can I get the program in my code to do what I typed in it? 
It should look like this:

http://nifty.stanford.edu/2011/schwarz-evil-hangman/

My link to all my code: https://github.com/michaelbao00/Evil-Hangman

My code for my main class (titled Hangman):

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.IOException;

    public class Hangman {
        public static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            Hangman Game = new Hangman();
            Game.startGame();
        }
        public Hangman() {

        }
        public void startGame() throws IOException{
            System.out.println("How long do you want the word to be? (The input must be an integer) \n");
            int wordLength = scan.nextInt();
            findWords(wordLength);
        }
        public void findWords(int length) throws IOException{
            FileReader filereader = new FileReader("dictionary1.txt");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(filereader);
            String word=reader.readLine();
            ArrayList<String> wordList = new ArrayList();
            for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
                word = reader.readLine();
                if(word.length()==length){
                    wordList.add(word);

                }

                }

                }

            }
```

Code for RealHangMan class:

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class RealHangMan {
    public final String DICTIONARY = "dictionary1.txt";
    private final int NUMGUESS = 6;
    private ArrayList<String> _activeList;
    private int _L;
    private String[] _currentAnswer; 
    private int _shownLetters;
    private int _triesRemaining;
    private boolean _gameOver;
    private ArrayList<String> _guessed;
    private List<String> alphabet = Arrays.asList("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split(""));
    public RealHangMan(int length, String dictionary) throws IOException {
        _L = length;
        _gameOver = false;
        _triesRemaining = NUMGUESS;
        _guessed = new ArrayList<String>(NUMGUESS);
        _currentAnswer = new String[_L];
        for (int i = 0; i < _L; i++) {
            _currentAnswer[i] = "_";
        }
        _shownLetters = 0;
        _activeList = new ArrayList<String>();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(DICTIONARY));
        try {
            String line = br.readLine();

            while (line != null) {
                if(line.length() == _L) {
                    String[] chars = line.split("");
                    List<String> charlist = Arrays.asList(chars);
                    HashSet s = new HashSet(charlist);
                    if (s.size() == _L) {
                        _activeList.add(line);                  
                    }   
                }
                line = br.readLine();
            }           
        } finally {
            br.close();
        }
    }

    public void printSortedGuesses() {
        Collections.sort(_guessed);
        if(_guessed.size() <= 13) {
            System.out.println("Guessed " + _guessed);
        } else {
            ArrayList<String> rest = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (String s : alphabet) {
                if(! _guessed.contains(s)) {
                    rest.add(s);
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Not Guessed " + rest);

        }

    }
    public boolean isGameOver() {
        return _gameOver;
    }
    public void displayAnswer() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (String s : _currentAnswer) {
            sb.append(s);
            sb.append(" ");
        }
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }

    public void showActiveList() {
        System.out.println("Active list has " + _activeList.size() + " words:");
        for (String w : _activeList) {
            System.out.println(w);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    public void update(String letter) {
        _guessed.add(letter);
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> candidateSets = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < _L+1; i++) {
            candidateSets.add(new ArrayList<String>());
        }
        //System.out.println("Pre: Size of activelist: " + _activeList.size());

        for( String word : _activeList) {
            String[] wordArray = word.split("");

            boolean notFound = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < _L; i++) {
                if (wordArray[i].equals(letter)) {
                    notFound = false;
                    candidateSets.get(i).add(word);
                }
            }
            if (notFound) {
                candidateSets.get(_L).add(word);
            }
        }

        int maxIndex = 0;
        int max = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < _L + 1; i++) {
            int len = candidateSets.get(i).size();
            // System.out.println("Candidate Set " + i + " len " + len);
            if (len > max) {
                max = len;
                maxIndex = i;
            }
        }
        if (maxIndex == _L) {
            _triesRemaining--;
            if (_triesRemaining == 0){
                System.out.println("You lose");
                showActiveList();
                _gameOver = true;
            } else {
                System.out.print("Tries:" + _triesRemaining + "   ");
            }
        } else {
            _currentAnswer[maxIndex] = letter;
            displayAnswer();
            _shownLetters++;
            if (_shownLetters == _L) {
                System.out.println("You win");
                _gameOver = true;
            }
        }
        _activeList = candidateSets.get(maxIndex);
        System.out.print("Uncertainty: " + _activeList.size() + "  ");
        printSortedGuesses();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String dict = args[0];
        System.out.println("dict " + dict);

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please input a wordlength");
        int wordlength = in.nextInt();
        RealHangMan game = new RealHangMan(wordlength , dict);
        while (! game.isGameOver()) {
            game.displayAnswer();
            System.out.print("Please guess a letter.  ");
            String letter = in.nextLine();
            game.update(letter);
        }
        in.close();
    }

}
```

dictionary1.txt file : http://nifty.stanford.edu/2011/schwarz-evil-hangman/dictionary.txt

Comment: Please check out the [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section of the [help] site, in particular the section on *"Help others reproduce the problem"*: `"...also include the code in your question itself. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time."`

Comment: I still do not know how to fix my code though.

Comment: If your problem is not a duplicate, then please *improve your question*, including posting your code here in your question as a [mcve], and not in a link.

Comment: After `int wordlength = in.nextInt();` call `in.nextLine();` to grab the end-of-line token, and see if it works better.

Comment: I tried that and it still does not work. Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: What do you expect? Your EvilHangman does nothing besides reading the number of letters and building a word list. It neither calls RealHangman nor does it implement the game itself.

Comment: Ok, but I do not know how to call RealHangMan and implement it into my Hangman class. Can you show me how?